# When proving $S$ is a subring, why do we prove that S is closed under subtraction not addition?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

I see that the definition of a subring requires that a subring should be closed under subtraction.
But what I learned was that to be a subring, it should be closed under addition and multiplication. Where does that subtraction come from? Does it have something to do with inverse?

Comment: Where did you get that from?

Comment: @ChubbyChef which one? the definition?

Comment: Usually the procedure is to show separately that the subring is closed under addition and *also* that each element of the subring has an additive inverse. The answer below sums up the connection nicely.

Comment: @ChubbyChef I need to show additive inverse because of multiplication? Why do I need additive inverse?

Comment: I guess this is from the definition of subring in chapter 7.1 Dummit and Foote.

Answer (score 4):

Being closed under addition and multiplication is not enough; after all, $\Bbb Z^+$ is closed under addition and multiplication, but it is not a subring of $\Bbb Z$. For each element $x$ of $S$, $-x$ must also belong to $S$. And if $S$ is closed under subtraction, then it is true that it is closed under addition and also that $x\in S\implies-x\in S$.